# How to click on this particular button from VBA?

Tags: vba, button

I have a simple VBA code (see below), that goes to a webpage, selects some value, clicks the “Begin download” button, and then saves the file.  The problem is I am stuck at the “clicking the download button” part.  Can someone help?

Here is the code:

```
Sub Treasury_Auc_Notes()

    Dim IE As Object

    Set IE = Nothing
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate "http://www.treasurydirect.gov/RI/OFAuctions?form=ndnld&typesec=notes"

    While IE.Busy
        DoEvents
Wend

    IE.Document.All.Item("begYr").Value = "2012"
    With IE.Document.getElementsByName("cols")
        .Item(0).Checked = True
    End With

    'Click "Begin download" button  (this is where I am stuck)
    'Choose Save Open or Cancel   (I haven’t got to this part yet)

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename


End Sub
```

Comment: you need to create another object to represent the button, probably by using the `GetElementsByTagName` method, then you can invoke the object's `.Click` method.

Answer (score 0):

This one's tricky, and due to restrictive security on my laptop, I'm not able to verify this 100%, but try:

```
While IE.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Wend

IE.Document.All.Item("begYr").Value = "2012"
With IE.Document.getElementsByName("cols")
    .Item(0).Checked = True
End With
Dim ele As Object

For Each ele In IE.Document.Forms
    If ele.Action = "/RI/OFAuctions" Then
        ele.Submit
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

You may have to use `SendKeys` (I think `Application.SendKeys "o"`)  method to open the file then use VBA to save the `ActiveWorkbook` to the desired location.   I'm not able to test `SendKeys` for reasons mentioned below.

Or, I'm pretty sure there is a WinAPI functions that can do this more reliably than `SendKeys`.  You'll need to get the `hWnd` of the Save dialog and do some other stuff to force it to open/save.   This is fairly advanced VBA that I probably have a reference to somewhere, but rarely need to use it.  If you have trouble with this particular part, I would urge you to ask a separate question "**How to get the hWnd of File Save dialog and download file from IE**" or something like that.

**NOTE:** I can't test the `SendKeys` method.  When I use the above code, I am fairly certain the file is being downloaded, but it is going to a temporary folder that is hidden, and difficult to find. In any case, it does appear to be downloading with some manual intervention.  I get this warning:

[image]

I click to ignore that (I have no idea how to automate this part, I'm just trying to validate that the form `.Submit` method actually worked), and after some creative searching (temporary internet files get dumped in a strange/hidden folder usually) I verify the file is downloaded, although it is showing as a TXT extension instead of CSV.

[image]

If instead of using VBA, I click on the button manually, and I choose to "open" the file opens as CSV and has the same path to that temporary internet location.